# How does RBS work with crawling in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: 2013, rbs

If you're using RBS to externalize content from the content database, what happens when the BLOB content is crawled? Will it be pulled back to the content database, or will it remain in the RBS? Or will crawling only create a substantial amount of network traffic, but the content will remain externalized and still be crawled? Should crawling be disabled for externalized BLOBs?